# Maven plugin which will export to MANIFEST.MF git information

Tags: git, maven

I would like to add maven plugin to my project which will can retrieve information from git repository about:

- current branch name
- last n hash commits with authors

I would appreciate if someone recommend me such maven plugin

Comment: there's a bunch of methods to retrieve this info, e.g. using the standard [Maven Exec Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). You may also look at [this](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/) plugin

Comment: [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) looks like what you are searching for...

Comment: I will try those plugins. Thanks a lot!